# Empty curly braces and semicolon in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, find

What does

```
{} \;
```

string mean in bash?

I've seen it a couple of times, for example, to find and delete all files by name one must execute

```
find . -name "FILE-TO-FIND" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

What does this string do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both `{}` and `;` have special meanings in `bash` but in the context of `find`, it is `find` which actually interprets these two (actually we want `find` to interpret these two).

First of all, `-exec` is an action of `find`. `{}` and `;` are special parameters for the `-exec` predicate of `find`.

The syntax for the `-exec` action is:

```
-exec command ;
```

or

```
-exec command {} +
```

So we need to keep `{}` and `;` from being interpreted by shell beforehand.

In the context of `find .... -exec`:

- `{}` indicates (contains) the result(s) from the `find` expression i.e. `find . -name "FILE-TO-FIND"` in this case. Note that empty curly braces `{}` have no special meaning to shell so we can get away without escaping `{}`
- As `bash` treats `;` as end of a command, we need to escape this with `\` i.e. `\;` so that it can be parsed by `-exec` not by `bash` itself.

Comment: So what does `;` do when interpreted by `find`?

Comment: @spiderface check my edits